# Throw $400$ dice, find the probability that at least $50$ of them are $1$

Tags: probability

$X:$ number on a die after the throw

$Y:$ number of dice with $1$

$P(X=1) = 1/6$, so I was thinking about doing $P(Y \geq 50) = P(X=1)^{50} \cdot 400C50$, but this gave me a very large number that was obviously wrong.

Any idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Give [this](http://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/binomial.aspx) a read? You're looking for the culmulative binomial distribution.

Comment: With that large a number of dice, a Normal approximation could be good enough. It’ll certainly be easier to compute.

Comment: If you are looking for an exact value, then $\binom{400}{50}(\frac{1}{6})^{50}(\frac{5}{6})^{400-50}$ will tell you the probability of exactly fifty of the dice being $1$.  Add this to the probability that there are exactly $51$ dice, and add this to the probability exactly $52$ dice... etc... on up to all $400$ dice.  If you do not care about an exact value, this seems like a good time to use the "normal approximation to the binomial distribution."  Search your textbook or the web for more info on that.  Finally, as a language note, "dice" is already plural.  "Die" is the singular of dice.

Comment: @amd That's very true. Did not consider that.

Comment: @JMoravitz It's the binomial of Newton but it gives something ridiculous when you evaluate the probability of all  favorables events...it gives $\binom {400}{ 50} ( 1/6 + 5/6)^{400} $

Comment: @Isham Think about what you just said again.  It should be obviously incorrect.  Remember that the binomial theorem implies that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{400}\binom{400}{k}(\frac{1}{6})^k(\frac{5}{6})^{400-k}=1$.  That should be a subtle enough reminder what a final solution might look like.

Comment: @JMoravitz You're right...I made a mistake putting outside something I shouldn't.....Thank you